# Firebase function to return Json

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

It is a simple requirement - how do I return the entire json from a firebase database.

My function is as such [index.js]

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('./xxMyKeyxx.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://xxmyProjectxx.firebaseio.com'
});


exports.myQuery = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const original = req.query.text;


  return admin.database().ref('/myFbDatabase').once.xxx
  I lost it from here.
```

what is the syntax to return the Json that is sitting in my FB database /myFbDatabase ?
      });

Answer (score 11):

Subscribing to the 'value' event will give you the entire database

```
exports.myQuery = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   // Grab the text parameter.
   const original = req.query.text;

   admin
     .database()
     .ref('/myFbDatabase')
     .once('value', 
       snap =>  res.json(snap.val()),
       err => res.json(err)
     )
})
```

Comment: The return statement isn't necessary.  The `res.json(snap.val())` is the part that returns the json text.  But you're right, I forgot to put a closing parentheses on the last line.  Fixed

Comment: Somehow it does not return any data. just returns a null . The console log does not throw any error either. 

I verified, the myFbDatabase db node is very much there and is populated with data. 
Rules specified are fine, as another web hook that inserts data works fine with the same settings. 

is something amiss in the syntax ? 


exports.myQuery = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    admin
      .database()
      .ref('/myFbDatabase')
      .once('value', 
          snapshot =>  res.json(snapshot.val()),
          err => res.json(err)
      )
});

Comment: @DonVaughn The edit you made to the code (surrounding the entire call with `res.json`) results in an error.  Sending the data is already handled at the point where the data is ready inside the callback to `.once`.  Also, I'm not sure why you argued that a return statement is required.  As you said yourself, this is an express function, so all that's required is to send the response to the browser using the `res` object.

Comment: Yes, you are of course correct. Thanks for the update. I've deleted the comment to avoid confusion for anyone reading in the future.